# How to use Query Builder when different conditions

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

My question is like this:

According to different codition, may make different sql, like below:

Because my $excludIds may empty, so , I need to ignore it , when it's empty. And I use it like blow, but will get an error.

```
DB::table('recommends')
   -> join('topics', 'topics.id', '=', 'recommends.courseid')
   if(count($excludIds) > 0){
      -> whereNotIn('topics.id', $excludIds)
   }
   -> where('recommends.re_type', '=', $recommend_type)
   -> get();
```

So, how should I use DB query builder in this case

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Havent checked the query itself, but the logic is as follows:

```
$fluentBuilder = DB::table('recommends')
   -> join('topics', 'topics.id', '=', 'recommends.courseid')
   -> where('recommends.re_type', '=', $recommend_type);

   if(count($excludIds) > 0){
      $fluentBuilder->whereNotIn('topics.id', $excludIds);
   }

$result = $fluentBuilder->get();
```

Comment: oh, I missed Semicolon in if. Thanks Andreyco

Comment: You also need to store Fluent object somewhere. You missed that part too